# Add choices in ListView Django

Tags: django

I have the view which displays all transactions. I have a table with `contractors` and I want to display all rows from this table in the options to `<select>`. How can i do this?

My view:

```
class TransactionView(CustomPermissionRequired, ListView):
    # Переопределение из MultipleObjectMixin
    model = Transaction
    context_object_name = 'transactions'
    paginate_by = 20
    login_url = '/'

    permission_required = (
        'registration2.can_see_payments',
    )

    # Переопределение из TemplateResponseMixin
    template_name = 'payments.html'

    search_fields = [
        ('contractor_name', 'deal__service__contractor__name__icontains'),
        ('from_pay_date', 'payment_date__gte'),
        ('to_pay_date', 'payment_date__lte'),
        ('tr_id', 'id__icontains')
    ]

    # Переопределение из MultipleObjectMixin
    def get_queryset(self):
        print('get_def')
        filter_args = []
        filter_kwargs = {}
        for sf in self.search_fields:
            if sf[0] is not None:
                sf_value = self.request.GET.get(sf[0])
                if sf_value:
                    filter_kwargs[sf[1]] = sf_value

        return Transaction.objects.all().select_related('currency',
                                                  'payment_source__payment_type',
                                                  'deal__service__contractor'
                                                  ).filter(*filter_args, **filter_kwargs).order_by('-id')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TransactionView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        for sf in self.search_fields:
            if sf[0] is not None:
                context[sf[0]] = self.request.GET.get(sf[0])

        return context
```

My models `Transaction` and `Contractors`:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=False, primary_key=True)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deal = models.ForeignKey(Deal, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # service_instance = models.ForeignKey(ServiceInstance, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment_source = models.ForeignKey(PayerPaymentSource, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    context = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Contractors(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=False, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: the easiest way to do this is to use a `Form` with a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield). You can pass a queryset to the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show your HTML, but you start from a queryset to get the contractor names and ids.

```
contractors = Contractors.objects.all().order_by('name').values_list('id, 'name')
```

If you look at `list(contractors)` you will see it is a list of 2-tuples as required for  `choices`.

You can use it as such if you dynamically build a form, or you can pass it to your template and iterate through it there to build an options list

```
{% for c in contractors %} <option ... {{c.0}} ...   {{c.1}} ... {% endfor %}
```

There's also `forms.ModelChoiceField` which IIRC accepts a `queryset` (without `values_list()`) as an argument, and returns the selected [`Contractor`] instance as its entry in `form.cleaned_data`.

Comment: How i can transfer `contractors`  from view to template? I made one attempt to transfer both transactions and contractors but it was not successful.

Comment: Override ListView `get_context_data` method in your view.  See https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.list/ListView/ and Django docs.